# Postgres json_to_recordset with a table

Tags: json, postgresql

I've written a query that operates on a single JSON document (named 'json_source'), and which returns each element of an array (named 'codes') within the JSON as a separate row, as follows:

```
SELECT
        json_array_elements(x.codes)->>'code'
    FROM
        json_to_recordset(json_source->'findings') AS x(
            codes json
        );
```

I have a database table with a JSON column that contains a document with the same structure as json_source. How can I rewrite the query above so that it operates on the table (i.e. with multiple rows of JSON data) rather than just on a single JSON document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help:

```
SELECT
    json_array_elements(t.json_column->'findings')->>'code'
FROM
    your_table t;
```

Comment: I didn't think to dispense with json_to_recordset. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You'd use `json_to_recordset` as a lateral [table function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS) call after selecting the rows from your table:

```
SELECT
    json_array_elements(x.codes)->>'code'
FROM
    my_table mt,
    json_to_recordset(mt.json_column->'findings') AS x(codes json);
```